# Build Failure on Jenkins using the Testlink plug-in

Tags: plugins, jenkins, xml-rpc, testlink

I created a new project exactly as the [Jenkins TestLink plugin Tutorial](http://tupilabs.com/books/jenkins-testlink-plugin-tutorial/en/book.pdf), except for one thing, and that is I used Subversion to do the source code management, not Git used in the tutorial.

My OS is Windows 10, and TestLink Version is 1.9.3, Jenkins Version is 1.609.1.

Here is the Console Output:

```
ERROR: Build step failed with exception java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.Map

at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.util.Util.castToMap(Util.java:591)
at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.TestProjectService.getTestProjectByName(TestProjectService.java:115)
at br.eti.kinoshita.testlinkjavaapi.TestLinkAPI.getTestProjectByName(TestLinkAPI.java:438)
at hudson.plugins.testlink.TestLinkBuilder.getTestLinkSite(TestLinkBuilder.java:309)
at hudson.plugins.testlink.TestLinkBuilder.perform(TestLinkBuilder.java:186)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:761)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:203)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:160)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:536)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374) 

Build step 'Invoke TestLink' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Anybody has any idea how this happened?

By the way, I found no `Util.java` in the source code of this plugin I downloaded from Github, `TestProjectService.java` and `TestLinkAPI.java` either.

Comment: What is the Java version you are using?

Comment: The Java version in my Windows is 1.8.0_91.

Comment: Then I tried it again in Linux system once again, this time the java version is 1.7.0_95, and the result is the same. still didn't work.

Comment: Try downgrading your Maven version to 3.0.5 and see. Also the tutorial link you provided is not working.

Comment: I have downgraded my Maven version to 3.0.5 but it still does work...and the result is also the same. As for the book, here is the link: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/753702/jenkins.pdf

Comment: What is the Jenkins plugin version you are using? You can try building the latest plugin and installing it from here https://github.com/jenkinsci/testlink-plugin

Comment: I have updated it into the latest version of 3.12 through Jenkins, but not through the github link you provided cuz I don't know how to, however, it still didn't work.  Is it possible that I wrote you an email about the configuration of the build, for I'm afraid there is something wrong with the SCM part. My email address is snowmanlarry@gmail.com, you may either write an email to me so I know it's you or leave your email address here. Appreciate that.

Comment: i have the same problem, the project is pretty simple executing one shell command. but i get the same error as posted above.